# How to keep save, update and view local data on Android?

Tags: java, android, local-storage

I'm downloading a list of town and city names from a server as a JSON file and parse them to become objects/strings. I need to download this data only once when the app is launched for the first time after the download, save this data to local storage of the Android device to be used to fill spinner (dropdown/combo box) menus and update the data only when the user wants to/needs to. What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: You can save it in SQLlite DB if you are already using it. If its not too much data and your app doesn't use SQLlite anywhere it might seem  a lot of work and then you can save that in SharedPreference as well.

Comment: Thanks! I'll use SharedPreferences. It looks like exacty what I needed.

Comment: Shared preferences is used to store small amount of data, while SQLite database is used for large amount of data

Comment: @GorkemSahin My pleasure. Have added the comment as an answer to be marked as complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments -

You can save it in SQLlite DB if you are already using it. If its not too much data and your app doesn't use SQLlite anywhere, it might seem a lot of work and then you can save that in SharedPreference as well. Just dont try to store too much data in Shared Preference

Answer (score 0):

**Some strategies that might help, the common logic are:**

---

- Strategy for static data that you need ONLY once:****

  1. Check if the data your looking for exists in your local storage.
  2. Get that data from storage

---

- Strategy for data you may need more then once and you have no version control from the server:

  1. Check if the data your looking for exists in your local storage.
  2. Check if that data is updated to the latest version
  3. If true - Get that data from storage
  4. If false - remove data from storage and download the latest data.

---

- Strategy for data you may need more then once and you do have version control from the server:

  1. Get your local data version - if doesn't exist move to phase 5
  2. Check with server that your version is up to date.
  3. If up to date - get data from local storage
  4. If old - Insert data from server
  5. Get data from storage

---

**Local storage options:**

1. [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) - this is a Key/Value type of storage, great for small things but from my experience you can save big data here as well, but I wouldn't advice that.
2. [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) - android's new Persistence Library
3. [SugerORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/) - third party library, very good and popular
4. [GreenDAO](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/) - third party library, also good and popular
5. [Other Database libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/25) - Sql and NonSql based solutions
6. The most old school - save data to a file using [OutputStreamWriter](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html)

**In Conclusion:**

Choose what ever seem to help you with your current and future tasks, the way you use these options is the same (using the strategies I wrote at the top) but with different methods.

I don't know what's the scale of your project is, that's why you'll have to choose the right way for you.

Wishing you good luck! =D